# Regression predictions cap at specific value

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, tensorflow-estimator

When I make predictions with my model, and then plot the predictions vs the actual values, I can see a very definied point where the predictions max out (should look like a line)
[image: Caps at about 800]

The code for my model

```
train_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
train_features,
y=train_label,
batch_size=64,
num_epochs=None,
shuffle=True
)


def my_rmse(labels, predictions):
    pred_values = predictions['predictions']
    return {'rmse': tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(tf.cast(labels,"float64"), tf.cast(pred_values, "float64"))}


model = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor(dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns, 
                                                dnn_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.001),
                                                dnn_hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256, 128],
                                                dnn_dropout=.2,
                                                dnn_activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                                batch_norm=True,
                                   linear_feature_columns=linear_columns)
model =  tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(model, my_rmse)
```

I figured it would be an issue with my activation function, but changing my activation only causes the max line to change in value or get slightly fuzzier.

Another example with tanh activation
[image: :(]

I've also tried scaling the labels and removing outliers, which improved accuracy, but didn't solve the problem

As requested results with rescaling:
[image]

Code for rescaling:

```
data = data[np.abs(data.VALUES-data.VALUES.mean()) <= (3*data.VALUES.std())] #remove outliers
data['VALUES'] = (data['SALES']-data['SALES'].mean())/(data['VALUES'].max()-data['VALUES'].min())
```

Plots of Labels after scaling:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show your results for when you rescale your target values? Something like `y /= y.max()`

Comment: Also, are you using a GPU? Might wanna use float32 instead of float64

Comment: Updated with results, and yeah I'm using GPU, I'll try float32

Comment: So this doesn't sound like something we can easily work out from stackoverflow... We'd need to explore your data and predictions a bit further. If I were you I would start of by plotting a sample of the data, not the whole dataset. I can't make heads or tails from that plot really (aside from the obvious boundaries). Other things that would help us out are quantile values and histograms, so we can get the gist of your data. I suspect that your dataset is unbalanced and the model is not catching up to edge cases, but I might be wrong

Comment: The plots I provided are only 10% of the data set, and in terms of these other plots, what are you asking for? Plots of my predictions? Of the features? Labels?

Comment: What I want are some plots that would show me the density difference from `0 < y < 500` and `y > 500`. So quantiles and histograms of your labels. 10% of your dataset still seems like too much for that kind of plot

Comment: Other things that might be screwing you up: Your labels are not properly aligned to your features, your features are too noisy (to the point where the labels are not correlated with your features at all), you're not using enough epochs

Comment: I put a lot of work into cleaning up the features and can see correlations when plotting them, and my loss plateaus before 5000 steps, so using more epochs doesn't do much. I added more plots to my original post

Comment: What's the std value? Maybe you're removing non-outliers with your 3*std code. Maybe that clear threshold comes from exactly the 3*std value

Comment: Also... It looks like the clear predictions threshold is pretty close to the third quantile... Would you know anything about that?

Comment: The threshold was there before I started removing outliers, and isn't the third quartile at around 0.05 whereas the threshold is above 0.25?

Comment: Sorry I misread that plot, but I mean the end of the right whisker (I'm not sure what metric that would represent in your case)

Comment: If I remember high school statistics correctly that represents Q3 + 1.5 * (Q3 - Q1)

Comment: Well... I'm sticking to my unbalanced dataset theory. It does seem that the vast majority of your data lies below the predictions threshold. If you do some exploration and find that this is indeed the case, you can probably bootstrap the less dense end of the data, or give some kind of higher weighting